# Java method overloading confusion

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, overloading

In a server code, I have a `ProtocolHandler` class which reads from the socket, finds out which type of packet it's dealing with and dispatches it to the client. I'm trying to have the following architecture:

```
public interface Packet {
    //...
}

public class ClientInformations implements Packet {
    //...
}

public class ProtocolHandler {
    //....
    public void bytesReceived(byte[] bytes) {
        //... Determine the type of the packet
        Packet packet = determineTypeOfPacketAndRead(bytes);

        // Here  I already have the packet object built,
        // like ClientInformations@1a1a1a1a[...]

        client.packetReceived(packet);
    }
    //...
}

public class Client {
    //...
    public void packetReceived(Packet pkt) { 
        System.out.println("Unimplemented packet received.");
    }

    public void packetReceived(ClientInformations ci) {

    }

    //...
}
```

(I don't know how to explain it easily with words). The problem is, I really thought `packetReceived(ClientInformations)` would be called, but it's not. It's calling the more general `packetReceived(Packet)` method. Am I wrong? How can I still use the same architecture then?

--EDIT

Now I understand why that happens. The problem is, i have other packet classes, such as `Movement`, `Sync`, `Spawn`. I wanted to ease adding new packets by just having to add a new method to the `Client` class. Isn't there another way of doing that then? I mean, a way to  **automatically** analyse the type of the `packet` object at runtime and doing the most specific method call?

Comment: Can you add all relevant code of `bytesReceived`? I cannot know of which type `packet` is, even though you have added `System.out.println(packet)`, I'd rather not focus on that.

Comment: I assume that `determineTypeOfPacketAndRead` is declared to returns `Packet`. Because of that compiler cant link it to `packetReceived(ClientInformations ci)`. You can do it manually by casting result to `ClientInformations` after checking its type with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is a single-dispatch language, so the trick is to learn to leverage that to the best effect possible.

In your case, you do not need to dispatch on the `Client` type, but you do need it against the `Packet` type. Let this requirement guide your design: instead of adding method overloads to `Client`, have *Packet* contain the handling code in a method like

```
void handle(Client c)
```

and make everything from the client available to the `Packet`. This will give you the chance to provide different handling in each specialization of `Packet`.

Unfortunately, the type dispatched on must the type *owning* the method in question, which may hurt your need to separate concerns. This could be accomplished with even more architecture, but I hope this guideline will help you on your way.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are having `Packet packet = determineTYpeOfPacketAndRead(bytes)`, as there is hardly an other way the code would else compile.

So the *reference* type is `Packet` (at compile-time), even though the *object* type is `ClientInformations` (at runtime).

And as specified in the Java Language Specification Chapter 15 onto *Method Overloading*.

> The most specific method is chosen at compile-time; its descriptor determines what method is actually executed at run-time.

**UPDATE:** Your code currently works, because you have no ambiguity in your code, even though it does not behave the way you want. However you will not be able to extend this code, as it will lead to issues, let me illustrate:

An earlier suggestion of mine was the following:

```
public class Client {
    //...
    public void unknownPacketReceived(Packet pkt) { 
        System.out.println("Unimplemented packet received.");
    }

    public void packetReceived(ClientInformations ci) {

    }

    //...
}
```

However this cannot work as a `ClientInformations` object is something more sophisticated as a simple `Packet` object/interface, it will give the following compile error:

```
incompatible types: Packet cannot be converted to ClientInformations
```

This happens as the *reference* type is still only `Packet`, while you want to lift it to being a `ClientInformations`.

It could work however if you would call it as:

```
client.receivedPacket((ClientInformations)packet)
```

This can do no harm in your case as on runtime they are of the same type, so nothing is lost in the conversion, this would need to be accompanied with an `instanceof` tree, which is why you are back at step zero now.

This program is not *just* going to work, I'd suggest to change your design if you want it to be simple, continuing this path *may* be an option if you are working on a legacy application and cannot *just* change things, but it won't be easy.

Comment: More information [here](http://geekexplains.blogspot.be/2009/06/choosing-most-specific-method-tricky.html).

Comment: Ok, I understand now, but does this means I can't do this kind of thing? I was hoping adding new packet types would be as simple as adding another method to the `Client` class...

Comment: That I cannot answer, (maybe someone else can), you surely need to have something like `packetReceived()` and `unknownPacketReceived()` though.

Comment: Should I open a new question on that topic?

Comment: @wingleader I am not sure if that is an option in your case but maybe consider overwriting rather then overloading. What I mean is trying to add some method to your interface and implement it differently in each of `ClientInformationsX` class. This way when you use `myPacket.mySpecialMethod(client)` you will get results based on actual type of `ClientInformationsX`.

Comment: @wingleader I am checking it out currently.

Comment: @wingleader Did your code even compile? I can't get a similar coding example to work (yet) without compile errors.

Comment: ._. It did compiled, though i'm off this architecture already, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, if I understand you correctly, the object you are passing is both a `Packet` and a `ClientInformations`, so neither of the methods really has any precedence over the others.

Just give the other method a different name and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it as follows:

```
public void bytesReceived(byte[] bytes) {
    //... Determine the type of the packet
    packet = determineTypeOfPacketAndRead(bytes);

    // Here  I already have the packet object built,
    // like ClientInformations@1a1a1a1a[...]

    if (packet instanceof ClientInformations) {
        ClientInformations ci = (ClientInformations)packet;
        client.packetReceived(ci); // this way, it's clear which method you want to call
    }
}
```

However, I prefer Tim B's suggestion to change the method name. I suggest `clientInformationsPacketReceived()`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to **why** has already been shown in the other answers. A solution (as far as I can tell) would require a change in your thought process.

Right now you're trying to put the logic to handle a packet in some sort of general class that handles this for every type of packet. This is a fairly common anti-pattern: creating 'manager' classes that will do the work for the specific objects.

An easy solution would be to simply put this logic in your classes themselves.

When you have the following situation

```
interface Packet {
    void packetReceived();
}

class ClientInformations implements Packet {
    @Override
    public void packetReceived() {
        System.out.println("I am ClientInformations");      
    }
}
```

You can just call `packetReceived` on your variable `packet` and this will do the work for you.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about the Single Responsibility Principle and the separation of data and logic (Packet implementors where supposed to just implement reading and writing the packet to/from the stream), but I'm leaning towards this approach now. It sure is different from the usual architecture I see, but it seems smart. I was thinking in adding another layer of separation from data and logic between packet data and action, do you believe that's necessary?

Comment: @wingleader It depends on who is working on the various packet implementations. On big projects you want maximum seperation, however on small projects you can get away with these things easily. And even in big projects it shouldn't be an issue *if* everyone follows your guidelines. Though in all honesty a packet itself has *nothing* to do with it being received or not, that is the `Client`s call and thus code.

Comment: Can you clarify what layer you'd place in between? Right now I'm a little torn whether or not this would be an acceptable architecture with regards to the SRP. I don't believe it violates the separation of data and logic since a `Packet` in itself doesn't contain any data-source-access and classes should definitely perform logic on themselves when possible, otherwise they're just variable wrappers.

Comment: But what if the handling code involves OP's `Client` class more than the `Packet` class? Handing over the code to the `Packet` hierarchy, and having to pass the `Client` instance to `packetReceived`, intimately couples these two types. Depending on the rest of the system, this may be entirely inappropriate.

Comment: Exactly as @MarkoTopoLnik said, the handling code involves checking `Client`'s values, doing some DB operations, sending new packets, etcetera. The current `Packet` class just reads itself from a stream and/or writes itself to a stream, like a C-struct with read and write functions.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: very true. In that situation I would look towards creating a class that holds a few fields and represents data necessary for packets to handle whatever it is they have to do. That way the client is loosely coupled and you've only sent the data that is actually needed (I don't imagine it will be much different for each packet). `Client` should prepare the variables needed in a `Packet` to do its operations, that way there's no coupling at all. Your method could then return a class `PacketResult` which could hold all the information to continue in `Client`.

Comment: OP, this is another important consideration: does `Client` need to know about each packet type that can be received? My guess: yes. In that case there is not much to be gained by relying on polymorphism/dynamic dispatch to vary the handling according to packet type. You could instead have a `Map<Class<? extends Packet>, PacketHandlingStrategy>` inside Client. `PacketHandlingStrategy` would be implemented as inner classes inside Client to facilitate acces to its internals. Note that in Java 8, the code for this would look much cleaner.

Comment: I like the suggestion of a `Map`, feel free to put it in your own answer so @wingleader can accept that one instead. It would mean very little overhead and none of the responsibility issues.

Comment: Thanks for the `Map` approach, I'll be using it. Looks very clean and modular, while keeping the data-logic separation. Could you please edit it into your answer, @MarkoTopoLnik? edit: Actually, I'm having problems imagining how to pass the packet object to the `PacketHandlingStrategy` object, without a `instanceof` tree. Could you edit a little help into your answer?

Comment: You would have `map.get(packet.getClass())`, which would replace the `instanceof` part. Currently I cannot think of a way to avoid an explicit downcast within the strategy's method, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can `typecast` your object reference to call the `packetReceived(ClientInformations)` instead of `packetReceived(Packet)`.

You can call like this `client.packetReceived((ClientInformations)packet);`